# Proxmox VLAN trunking to Cisco switch (2960)

Tags: vlan

I just got a Cisco Catalyst 2960 and wanted to use the to gigabit ports to trunk VM VLANs

The two gigabit ports are running to the Proxmox server, both set as Dot1Q trunks on the Cisco switch.

My question is, if I gave each VM a Vlan, for example: VM1 - VLAN 1, VM2 - Vlan 2, how would I configure Proxmox network interfaces for this?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxmox's interface configuration doesn't need to be changed. If you want to trunk VLANs, just assign VMs the same physical interface, then specify a VLAN in the same dialog box.